# Exception from cURL when attempting to arc diff (Error code 56)

Tags: git, curl, phabricator, arcanist

Im attempting to `arc diff` a local commit to a remote repository on bitbucket using Arcanist for Phabricator. This is the first time I have seen this error and I can not seem to find similar information on the internet. I have attempted `arc diff`-ing other branches and it works as expected.

> [cURL/56] (https://phabricator.website.com.au/api/differential.creatediff)  The cURL library raised an error while making a request. You may be able to find more information about this error (error code: 56) on the cURL site: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLERECVERROR

The information on the error in the link suggested states:

> CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56)
>
> Failure with receiving network data.

Answer (score 0):

The issues turned out to be the size of one of the files I was trying to diff.

The file was a json text file with a response from our API to save having to waiting when testing. The file was >1MB in size and removing it from the commit fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase your upload limits depending on your HTTP server.
This guide has some information about what to change.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_file_storage/#configuring-upload-limit